# How to fix an error that keeps informing me that an abstract keyword is not used and hence i need to declare a body

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
class Planner
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
}

class exe
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          List<Planner> t = new List<Planner>();
          FileStream fs = new FileStream("Scheduler.txt",
                           FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
          StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs)
          {
              string line = string.Empty;
              while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
              {
                 string[] lines = line.Split(' ').ToArray();
                 t.Add(new Planner() { firstName = lines[0], lastName = lines[1],
                 dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                  lines[2] + lines[3], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) });
          }
    }
    t = t.OrderBy(x => x.dateTime).ToList<Planner>()
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure error comes up in these lines? These are `automatic properties` and perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes it does, error cs0501

Comment: Which C# version do you use? Auto-Implemented properties are a feature of C# 3.0.

Comment: Which compiler you are using?

Comment: I think you need to post the whole class as well as the exact error message

Comment: Can you post the code for the full abstract class. Does a derived class and not just the auto properties.

Comment: 'Planner.firstName.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern

Comment: @OP - You need `backup field for firstName` and for other properties. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Auto implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) got introduced in `C#3.0`. If you are using version lesser than 3.0, you need `backup field` for your property like this -

```
private string firstName;
public string FirstName
{
  get
  { return firstName; }
  set
  { firtName = value; }
}
```

**From MSDN** -

> In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented properties make
>   property-declaration more concise when no additional logic is required
>   in the property accessors. They also enable client code to create
>   objects. When you declare a property as automatic, the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that
>   can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.